# The field of checkbox type isn't available when I try to make a new object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, relationships, new

The field of checkbox type isn't available when I try to make a new object.

[image]

Comment: It's not in your `Page layout`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Zaitsman please add the particular field which you need to the layout as shown below.
Go to Pagelayout-> select the layout -> search for the field -> Drag and drop the field in the required position -> Save it.

[image]
Please find more details in the [Reference link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_page_layouts#:%7E:text=The%20page%20layout%20editor%20lets,appear%20in%20the%20page%20details&text=Control%20which%20standard%20and%20custom%20buttons%20appear%20on%20records%20and%20related%20lists)